# How can I search for users, filtered by tag?

Tags: support

Is it possible to search for user rank (tab *"Reputation"*) filtered by tag on the *Users* page?

[image: Filter]

Comment: Does [the “Top users” link](//stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) not help?